# How to use patches to count ticks in weeks in a Netlogo shopping model?

Tags: model, netlogo, patch, agent

I have to create a Netlogo-world with N green patches for households and M blue patches for supermarkets. In the world turtles go from home (green patch) to the supermarket (blue patch) and back home again. I posted my code of this below.

Comment: I undid what seems like an accidental removal of most of the info which the existing answer was based on.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want the `week` variable to be a patch variable? In other words, why do you want patches to measure time?

I think you should consider two other options:

1. **Measure time with a global variable**: there already is the `ticks` global variable, but you can create your own global variable and every agent will be able to read it.
2. **Let your turtles measure how often they want to go to the shop**: each turtle can have a turtle-own variable that is used as a countdown. When the countdown reaches 0, the turtle will leave to visit the shop.

For example, if as I understood you want each turtle to visit their chosen shop every 70 ticks, you can do something like.

```
turtles-own [
  housePatch
  target
  storeVisited
  phase
  countdown
]


to setup
  clear-all
  reset-ticks
  
  ask n-of 10 patches [set pcolor blue]
  
  ask n-of 15 patches with [ pcolor != blue ][
    set pcolor green
    sprout 1 [
      set target one-of patches with [pcolor = blue]
      set housePatch patch-here
      set phase 1

      set color red
      set size 1
    ]
  ]
end 


to go
  ask turtles [
    ifelse (phase = 1)
      [shop]
      [return]
  ]
  
  ask turtles with [countdown > 0] [
    set countdown countdown - 1
  ]
  
  tick
end


to shop
  if (countdown = 0) [
    face target
    forward 1
  ]
  
  if (patch-here = target) [
    set storeVisited storeVisited + 1
    set phase 2
  ]
end


to return
  face housePatch
  forward 1
  
  if (patch-here = housePatch) [
    set countdown 70
    set phase 1
  ]
end
```

Let's explore the main things I implemented here:

1. **Phases**: The way you setup your model implies that, on most iterations of `go`, each turtle either executes `shop` or executes `return`. However, your `go` was:

```
to go
 ask turtles [
   shop
   return
 ]
end
```

This was creating some mess as I went to implement a countdown, so I thought to clearly split turtles' activities with a `phase` turtles-own variable: a value of 1 means that turtles will have to execute `shop`; a value of 2 means that turtles will have to execute `return`. The value of `phase` is set as 1 upon `setup` and every time a turtle returns home, and it is set as 2 every time a turtle reaches the shop.

As you can see, I removed `stay` from the model because it made turtles do nothing.

2. **Countdown**: Each turtle has a `countdown` variable, that is checked at the beginning of `shop`. If `countdown` reached the value of 0, then the turtle actually moves towards the shop. The value of `countdown` is left at its default of 0 upon `setup`, which means that at the beginning every turtle will start by moving towards the shop. Upon returning home after each visit to the shop, the value of `countdown` is set to 70. At every iteration of `go`, all turtles whose countdown is greater than zero will bring it down by one.

---

Note that I implemented some other minor changes to the code, some of them being:

- I removed `set storeVisited 0` from within the `setup` procedure. The default value of variables is 0 in NetLogo, so there is no need to set them to 0 at the beginning.
- At the end of `go`, you were using `reset-ticks` instead of `tick`.
- In `shop`, I substituted `if (pcolor = blue)` with `if (patch-here = target)`. This is because, on the way to `target`, a turtle might find itself on a blue patch which is not its target.

Comment: @JanJanssen Ah, I see. I think it would be ideal for you to do two things: (1) Clarify a bit more what is the intended mechanism (do you want each shop to count up to 70 ticks before calling the turtles that have it as preferred shop? would such 70th tick be the moment at which turtles are called, so that they start the journey from their house? how would that work considering that different turtles, at different distances, would visit the shop at different moments?).

Comment: @JanJanssen (2) Show what you tried so far and how it is not working. This not only is good practice on SO in general (broadly see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)), and especially in the case of homework questions, but it would also help us better understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: To clarify the assignment I will state it here:

1. each household buys food products once a week. A week should be determined by a patch variable called week that starts at zero; counts up each tick and resets when the week reaches 70 ticks.

2. After the week resets, one randomly selected household goes online (does not shop in a brick and mortar supermarket anymore) and turns their patch white

Comment: is this clearer to you?